# How to pass data from a parent Flutter web application to an iFrame child flutter web application in Dart

Tags: flutter, micro-frontend

I have two different flutter web application hosted on different server running on different domain. Both application has sign in features. Now our requirement changed and we have to serve one application with single domain. What I am trying to do it to load second flutter web application as iFrame. I am able to load it successfully but problem is it is showing sign in screen again. To avoid it I want to pass data through iFrame to child application so I can handle sign in things.

I tried so many approach like window.postMessagae(), MethodChannel but not working.

Is there any way to achieve this?  How to achieve this as microfrontend?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the token you've generated in your main application to the url you're using in the iFrame, for example, `"https://yourdomain.com/?token=${token}"`, so you can use this token in your secondary application to sign in the user

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am able to pass using query param. But i am facing one problem to refresh . When ever i pass updated token, it not reflecting updated one. it keeping cached older token in secondary application. How to reload iframe or cache clear , both parent and child

Answer (score 0):

I can feel your pain. One general approach is to use JWT for authentication and pass the token from the parent application to the child application.

Here's a great post:
https://dev.to/carminezacc/user-authentication-jwt-authorization-with-flutter-and-node-176l

here's a package: https://pub.dev/packages/jwt_decoder